# How do I drop rows from a pivot table that has columns with labels and sublabels in it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pivot table that I created using the following code:

```
pivot_2 = pd.pivot_table(pre_post_df_2, columns = ['pre_post_nota_ind','Party'],  index = ['uni_const_code'], values = ['votesh_percof_total']).reset_index()
pivot_2.rename(columns = {1:'post', 0:'pre'}, inplace = True) 
#I wrote the above code because pre_post_nota_ind takes 0 which represents pre and 1 which represents post
```

I get a pivot table (that is a data frame type) that looks something like this:

```
                    votesh_percof_total
pre_post_nota_ind    pre              post
uni_const_code  IND        IND        NOTA
0|10|1      71.932234   53.922378    33.827091
0|10|10     46.052632   NaN          40.106277
0|10|11     45.171340   28.443649    32.434116
0|10|12     63.429439   30.115420    NaN
0|10|13     30.000000   NaN          46.598414
```

Side note: The third and fourth columns both relate to the 'post' period hence they have a common head.

Basically, there are sub-columns in the pivot table above. I want to remove those rows for whose value in the NOTA column is `Nan`

I want the final output to be like:

```
                    votesh_percof_total
pre_post_nota_ind pre           post
uni_const_code  IND        IND        NOTA
0|10|1      71.932234   53.922378    33.827091
0|10|10     46.052632   NaN          40.106277
0|10|11     45.171340   28.443649    32.434116
0|10|13     30.000000   NaN          46.598414
```

I tried the following:
`pivot_2.dropna(subset = pivot_2['NOTA'])` 
and also
`pivot_2 = pivot_2.votesh_percof_total.post.notnull()]`

Both of them throw errors. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried `pivot_2.dropna(subset = ['NOTA'])` ? You may also need to add `inplace=True` if you aren't assigning to a new dataframe.

Comment: @Kurt Kline I did. I get the following error: ```KeyError: ['NOTA']```. I guess I need to solve how to subset columns with a common head.